# Unable to build release version

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, build, release

Debug version is running, but build error on **flutter build apk**, **flutter run --release**, and on releasing bundle too.

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                                
                                                                
                                                                                                                   
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.                                                                           
                                                                                                                   
* Where:                                                                                                           
Script '/home/mkmalik/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 904                              
                                                                                                                   
* What went wrong:                                                                                                 
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'.                                                       
> Process 'command '/home/mkmalik/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1                        
                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                   
BUILD FAILED in 7m 16s
```

flutter.gradle line: 904 (first line, 904)

```
project.exec {
            logging.captureStandardError LogLevel.ERROR
            executable flutterExecutable.absolutePath
            workingDir sourceDir
            if (localEngine != null) {
                args "--local-engine", localEngine
                args "--local-engine-src-path", localEngineSrcPath
            }
            if (verbose) {
                args "--verbose"
            } else {
                args "--quiet"
            }
            args "assemble"
            args "--depfile", "${intermediateDir}/flutter_build.d"
            args "--output", "${intermediateDir}"
```

stack trace (./gradlew build --stacktrace)

**

> Configure project :app

> Task :agora_rtc_engine:compileReleaseKotlin
> w: /home/mkmalik/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/agora_rtc_engine-3.3.3/android/src/main/java/io/agora/rtc/base/BeanCovertor.kt: (81, 44): 'lowLatency: Boolean' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: /home/mkmalik/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/agora_rtc_engine-3.3.3/android/src/main/java/io/agora/rtc/base/BeanCovertor.kt: (90, 51): 'backgroundColor: Int' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: /home/mkmalik/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/agora_rtc_engine-3.3.3/android/src/main/java/io/agora/rtc/base/Extensions.kt: (103, 16): 'delay: Int' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: /home/mkmalik/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/agora_rtc_engine-3.3.3/android/src/main/java/io/agora/rtc/base/RtcChannel.kt: (299, 56): 'setEncryptionSecret(String!): Int' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: /home/mkmalik/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/agora_rtc_engine-3.3.3/android/src/main/java/io/agora/rtc/base/RtcChannel.kt: (303, 56): 'setEncryptionMode(String!): Int' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: /home/mkmalik/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/agora_rtc_engine-3.3.3/android/src/main/java/io/agora/rtc/base/RtcEngine.kt: (425, 27): 'enableWebSdkInteroperability(Boolean): Int' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: /home/mkmalik/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/agora_rtc_engine-3.3.3/android/src/main/java/io/agora/rtc/base/RtcEngine.kt: (720, 27): 'setLocalVoiceChanger(Int): Int' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: /home/mkmalik/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/agora_rtc_engine-3.3.3/android/src/main/java/io/agora/rtc/base/RtcEngine.kt: (724, 27): 'setLocalVoiceReverbPreset(Int): Int' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: /home/mkmalik/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/agora_rtc_engine-3.3.3/android/src/main/java/io/agora/rtc/base/RtcEngine.kt: (898, 27): 'setEncryptionSecret(String!): Int' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: /home/mkmalik/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/agora_rtc_engine-3.3.3/android/src/main/java/io/agora/rtc/base/RtcEngine.kt: (902, 27): 'setEncryptionMode(String!): Int' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: /home/mkmalik/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/agora_rtc_engine-3.3.3/android/src/main/kotlin/io/agora/agora_rtc_engine/AgoraRtcEnginePlugin.kt: (135, 50): Call uses reflection API which is not found in compilation classpath. Make sure you have kotlin-reflect.jar in the classpath

> Task :agora_rtc_engine:compileProfileKotlin
> w: /home/mkmalik/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/agora_rtc_engine-3.3.3/android/src/main/java/io/agora/rtc/base/BeanCovertor.kt: (81, 44): 'lowLatency: Boolean' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: /home/mkmalik/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/agora_rtc_engine-3.3.3/android/src/main/java/io/agora/rtc/base/BeanCovertor.kt: (90, 51): 'backgroundColor: Int' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: /home/mkmalik/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/agora_rtc_engine-3.3.3/android/src/main/java/io/agora/rtc/base/Extensions.kt: (103, 16): 'delay: Int' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: /home/mkmalik/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/agora_rtc_engine-3.3.3/android/src/main/java/io/agora/rtc/base/RtcChannel.kt: (299, 56): 'setEncryptionSecret(String!): Int' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: /home/mkmalik/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/agora_rtc_engine-3.3.3/android/src/main/java/io/agora/rtc/base/RtcChannel.kt: (303, 56): 'setEncryptionMode(String!): Int' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: /home/mkmalik/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/agora_rtc_engine-3.3.3/android/src/main/java/io/agora/rtc/base/RtcEngine.kt: (425, 27): 'enableWebSdkInteroperability(Boolean): Int' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: /home/mkmalik/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/agora_rtc_engine-3.3.3/android/src/main/java/io/agora/rtc/base/RtcEngine.kt: (720, 27): 'setLocalVoiceChanger(Int): Int' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: /home/mkmalik/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/agora_rtc_engine-3.3.3/android/src/main/java/io/agora/rtc/base/RtcEngine.kt: (724, 27): 'setLocalVoiceReverbPreset(Int): Int' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: /home/mkmalik/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/agora_rtc_engine-3.3.3/android/src/main/java/io/agora/rtc/base/RtcEngine.kt: (898, 27): 'setEncryptionSecret(String!): Int' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: /home/mkmalik/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/agora_rtc_engine-3.3.3/android/src/main/java/io/agora/rtc/base/RtcEngine.kt: (902, 27): 'setEncryptionMode(String!): Int' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: /home/mkmalik/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/agora_rtc_engine-3.3.3/android/src/main/kotlin/io/agora/agora_rtc_engine/AgoraRtcEnginePlugin.kt: (135, 50): Call uses reflection API which is not found in compilation classpath. Make sure you have kotlin-reflect.jar in the classpath

> Task :agora_rtc_engine:compileDebugKotlin
> w: /home/mkmalik/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/agora_rtc_engine-3.3.3/android/src/main/java/io/agora/rtc/base/BeanCovertor.kt: (81, 44): 'lowLatency: Boolean' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: /home/mkmalik/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/agora_rtc_engine-3.3.3/android/src/main/java/io/agora/rtc/base/BeanCovertor.kt: (90, 51): 'backgroundColor: Int' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: /home/mkmalik/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/agora_rtc_engine-3.3.3/android/src/main/java/io/agora/rtc/base/Extensions.kt: (103, 16): 'delay: Int' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: /home/mkmalik/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/agora_rtc_engine-3.3.3/android/src/main/java/io/agora/rtc/base/RtcChannel.kt: (299, 56): 'setEncryptionSecret(String!): Int' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: /home/mkmalik/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/agora_rtc_engine-3.3.3/android/src/main/java/io/agora/rtc/base/RtcChannel.kt: (303, 56): 'setEncryptionMode(String!): Int' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: /home/mkmalik/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/agora_rtc_engine-3.3.3/android/src/main/java/io/agora/rtc/base/RtcEngine.kt: (425, 27): 'enableWebSdkInteroperability(Boolean): Int' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: /home/mkmalik/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/agora_rtc_engine-3.3.3/android/src/main/java/io/agora/rtc/base/RtcEngine.kt: (720, 27): 'setLocalVoiceChanger(Int): Int' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: /home/mkmalik/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/agora_rtc_engine-3.3.3/android/src/main/java/io/agora/rtc/base/RtcEngine.kt: (724, 27): 'setLocalVoiceReverbPreset(Int): Int' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: /home/mkmalik/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/agora_rtc_engine-3.3.3/android/src/main/java/io/agora/rtc/base/RtcEngine.kt: (898, 27): 'setEncryptionSecret(String!): Int' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: /home/mkmalik/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/agora_rtc_engine-3.3.3/android/src/main/java/io/agora/rtc/base/RtcEngine.kt: (902, 27): 'setEncryptionMode(String!): Int' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: /home/mkmalik/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/agora_rtc_engine-3.3.3/android/src/main/kotlin/io/agora/agora_rtc_engine/AgoraRtcEnginePlugin.kt: (135, 50): Call uses reflection API which is not found in compilation classpath. Make sure you have kotlin-reflect.jar in the classpath

> Task :agora_rtc_engine:lint
> Calling mockable JAR artifact transform to create file: /home/mkmalik/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/8a531961b8210f93eb2287d6c9845042/android.jar with input /home/mkmalik/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-28/android.jar
> Ran lint on variant release: 6 issues found
> Ran lint on variant profile: 6 issues found
> Ran lint on variant debug: 6 issues found
> Wrote HTML report to file:///home/mkmalik/Desktop/MeetMeFit/mmf%201.0.3%20(copy)/mmf%2013%20may%202021/meetmefit/build/agora_rtc_engine/reports/lint-results.html
> Wrote XML report to file:///home/mkmalik/Desktop/MeetMeFit/mmf%201.0.3%20(copy)/mmf%2013%20may%202021/meetmefit/build/agora_rtc_engine/reports/lint-results.xml

> Task :agora_rtc_engine:lint FAILED
> *********************************************************
> WARNING: This version of flutter_webview_plugin will break your Android build if it or its dependencies aren't compatible with AndroidX.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':agora_rtc_engine:lint'.

> Lint found errors in the project; aborting build.

Fix the issues identified by lint, or add the following to your build script to proceed with errors:
...
android {
lintOptions {
abortOnError false
}
}
...

The first 3 errors (out of 6) were:
/home/mkmalik/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/agora_rtc_engine-3.3.3/android/src/main/kotlin/io/agora/agora_rtc_engine/AgoraSurfaceViewFactory.kt:59: Error: Call requires API level 26 (current min is 16): java.lang.reflect.Executable#getParameters [NewApi]
function.parameters.forEach { parameter ->
~~~~~~~~~~
/home/mkmalik/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/agora_rtc_engine-3.3.3/android/src/main/kotlin/io/agora/agora_rtc_engine/AgoraSurfaceViewFactory.kt:61: Error: Call requires API level 26 (current min is 16): java.lang.reflect.Parameter#getName [NewApi]
if (map.containsKey(parameter.name)) {
~~~~
/home/mkmalik/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/agora_rtc_engine-3.3.3/android/src/main/kotlin/io/agora/agora_rtc_engine/AgoraSurfaceViewFactory.kt:62: Error: Call requires API level 26 (current min is 16): java.lang.reflect.Parameter#getName [NewApi]
parameters.add(map[parameter.name])
~~~~

- Try:
  Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Exception is:
  org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':agora_rtc_engine:lint'.
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:207)
  at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:263)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:205)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:186)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:114)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:62)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
  at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:41)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:370)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:357)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:350)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
  at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:127)
  at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:191)
  at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:182)
  at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:124)
  at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
  at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
  at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
  Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Lint found errors in the project; aborting build.

Fix the issues identified by lint, or add the following to your build script to proceed with errors:
...
android {
lintOptions {
abortOnError false
}
}
...

The first 3 errors (out of 6) were:
/home/mkmalik/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/agora_rtc_engine-3.3.3/android/src/main/kotlin/io/agora/agora_rtc_engine/AgoraSurfaceViewFactory.kt:59: Error: Call requires API level 26 (current min is 16): java.lang.reflect.Executable#getParameters [NewApi]
function.parameters.forEach { parameter ->
~~~~~~~~~~
/home/mkmalik/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/agora_rtc_engine-3.3.3/android/src/main/kotlin/io/agora/agora_rtc_engine/AgoraSurfaceViewFactory.kt:61: Error: Call requires API level 26 (current min is 16): java.lang.reflect.Parameter#getName [NewApi]
if (map.containsKey(parameter.name)) {
~~~~
/home/mkmalik/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/agora_rtc_engine-3.3.3/android/src/main/kotlin/io/agora/agora_rtc_engine/AgoraSurfaceViewFactory.kt:62: Error: Call requires API level 26 (current min is 16): java.lang.reflect.Parameter#getName [NewApi]
parameters.add(map[parameter.name])
~~~~

```
    at com.android.tools.lint.gradle.LintGradleExecution.abort(LintGradleExecution.java:206)
    at com.android.tools.lint.gradle.LintGradleExecution.lintAllVariants(LintGradleExecution.java:530)
    at com.android.tools.lint.gradle.LintGradleExecution.analyze(LintGradleExecution.java:96)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at com.android.tools.lint.gradle.api.ReflectiveLintRunner.runLint(ReflectiveLintRunner.kt:38)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.LintBaseTask.runLint(LintBaseTask.java:100)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.LintGlobalTask.lint(LintGlobalTask.java:47)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:104)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:49)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:28)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:722)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:689)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:569)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:554)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:537)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.access$300(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:108)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.executeWithPreviousOutputFiles(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:278)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:267)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.lambda$execute$1(ExecuteStep.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:67)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:73)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CatchExceptionStep.execute(CatchExceptionStep.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.executeWithoutCache(CacheStep.java:159)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:72)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:92)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:85)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:39)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:76)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:94)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:79)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:74)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.lambda$execute$2(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:78)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:78)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:39)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadExecutionStateStep.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadExecutionStateStep.java:28)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultWorkExecutor.java:33)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:194)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:186)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:114)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:41)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:370)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:357)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:350)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:127)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:191)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execut
```

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.

See https://docs.gradle.org/6.4.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 3m 51s
70 actionable tasks: 45 executed, 25 up-to-date
**

Comment: Would  you mind adding the output after running running with the --stracktrace option or the other options mentioned in the output?

Comment: @LuisCárcamo stack trace been added

Comment: Try `flutter clean` and `flutter pug get`. If that doesn't work, try updating both your Dart Tools and Flutter Tools.

Comment: can you guide me how to do that? @LuisCárcamo

Answer (score 1):

From the complete stacktrace you can see

```
 Call requires API level 26 (current min is 16)
```

Which means you need to change the minSDK to 26. You can do that by updating it in the file `android/app/build.gradle`, changing `minSdkVersion 16` to `minSdkVersion 26`. Make sure to run `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get` after performing this change.

Comment: Does it still show `Call requires API level 26 (current min is 16)` in the full stacktrace message?

Comment: 1. See there are some deprecration warnings in the build, check out the documentation for the agora package in the current version you are using. https://docs.agora.io/en/faq/API%20Reference/java/deprecated.html

Comment: 2. https://github.com/AgoraIO/Agora-Flutter-SDK/pull/54 From this, seems like instead of minSdkVersion26, you need minSdkVersion28. If the issue persists, you may as well try opening an issue in the Agora-Flutter-SDK github repository.