# When installing Agora Flutter RTC package it gives Execution failed for task ':agora_rtc_engine:compileProfileKotlin' error

Tags: flutter, gradle, agora.io

i have a working flutter project but when i install agora RTC package it gives Execution failed for task **':agora_rtc_engine:compileDebugKotlin'**. error.
I'm not even using the package yet, i tried setting up the permissions and all the instructions in the [readme](https://pub.dev/packages/agora_rtc_engine) section but i think the issue is with the package itself, also my flutter project is null-safety migrated and it's working so I'm sure there's nothing wrong with my project.

I'm not using the package yet. It gives an error just by installing it.

here is the `app/gradle.build`:

```
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.malhamti_app"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

here is my `android/build.gradle`:

```
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.20'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

here is the gradle `--stacktrace`:
see full [stacktrace](https://jpst.it/2OTOL) (character limit)

```
> Task :agora_rtc_engine:compileProfileKotlin FAILED
e: /Users/doabletech/Development/Tools/flutter_sdk/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/agora_rtc_engine-5.1.0/android/src/main/kotlin/io/agora/agora_rtc_engine/AgoraRtcEnginePlugin.kt: (251, 18): Type mismatch: inferred type is String? but String was expected
e: /Users/doabletech/Development/Tools/flutter_sdk/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/agora_rtc_engine-5.1.0/android/src/main/kotlin/io/agora/agora_rtc_engine/AgoraSurfaceViewFactory.kt: (16, 1): Class 'AgoraSurfaceViewFactory' is not abstract and does not implement abstract base class member public abstract fun create(p0: Context?, p1: Int, p2: Any?): PlatformView defined in io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformViewFactory
e: /Users/doabletech/Development/Tools/flutter_sdk/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/agora_rtc_engine-5.1.0/android/src/main/kotlin/io/agora/agora_rtc_engine/AgoraSurfaceViewFactory.kt: (20, 3): 'create' overrides nothing
e: /Users/doabletech/Development/Tools/flutter_sdk/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/agora_rtc_engine-5.1.0/android/src/main/kotlin/io/agora/agora_rtc_engine/AgoraTextureViewFactory.kt: (12, 1): Class 'AgoraTextureViewFactory' is not abstract and does not implement abstract base class member public abstract fun create(p0: Context?, p1: Int, p2: Any?): PlatformView defined in io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformViewFactory
e: /Users/doabletech/Development/Tools/flutter_sdk/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/agora_rtc_engine-5.1.0/android/src/main/kotlin/io/agora/agora_rtc_engine/AgoraTextureViewFactory.kt: (17, 3): 'create' overrides nothing

> Task :agora_rtc_engine:compileDebugKotlin FAILED
e: /Users/doabletech/Development/Tools/flutter_sdk/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/agora_rtc_engine-5.1.0/android/src/main/kotlin/io/agora/agora_rtc_engine/AgoraRtcEnginePlugin.kt: (251, 18): Type mismatch: inferred type is String? but String was expected
e: /Users/doabletech/Development/Tools/flutter_sdk/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/agora_rtc_engine-5.1.0/android/src/main/kotlin/io/agora/agora_rtc_engine/AgoraSurfaceViewFactory.kt: (16, 1): Class 'AgoraSurfaceViewFactory' is not abstract and does not implement abstract base class member public abstract fun create(p0: Context?, p1: Int, p2: Any?): PlatformView defined in io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformViewFactory
e: /Users/doabletech/Development/Tools/flutter_sdk/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/agora_rtc_engine-5.1.0/android/src/main/kotlin/io/agora/agora_rtc_engine/AgoraSurfaceViewFactory.kt: (20, 3): 'create' overrides nothing
e: /Users/doabletech/Development/Tools/flutter_sdk/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/agora_rtc_engine-5.1.0/android/src/main/kotlin/io/agora/agora_rtc_engine/AgoraTextureViewFactory.kt: (12, 1): Class 'AgoraTextureViewFactory' is not abstract and does not implement abstract base class member public abstract fun create(p0: Context?, p1: Int, p2: Any?): PlatformView defined in io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformViewFactory
e: /Users/doabletech/Development/Tools/flutter_sdk/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/agora_rtc_engine-5.1.0/android/src/main/kotlin/io/agora/agora_rtc_engine/AgoraTextureViewFactory.kt: (17, 3): 'create' overrides nothing

> Task :agora_rtc_engine:compileReleaseKotlin FAILED
e: /Users/doabletech/Development/Tools/flutter_sdk/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/agora_rtc_engine-5.1.0/android/src/main/kotlin/io/agora/agora_rtc_engine/AgoraRtcEnginePlugin.kt: (251, 18): Type mismatch: inferred type is String? but String was expected
e: /Users/doabletech/Development/Tools/flutter_sdk/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/agora_rtc_engine-5.1.0/android/src/main/kotlin/io/agora/agora_rtc_engine/AgoraSurfaceViewFactory.kt: (16, 1): Class 'AgoraSurfaceViewFactory' is not abstract and does not implement abstract base class member public abstract fun create(p0: Context?, p1: Int, p2: Any?): PlatformView defined in io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformViewFactory
e: /Users/doabletech/Development/Tools/flutter_sdk/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/agora_rtc_engine-5.1.0/android/src/main/kotlin/io/agora/agora_rtc_engine/AgoraSurfaceViewFactory.kt: (20, 3): 'create' overrides nothing
e: /Users/doabletech/Development/Tools/flutter_sdk/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/agora_rtc_engine-5.1.0/android/src/main/kotlin/io/agora/agora_rtc_engine/AgoraTextureViewFactory.kt: (12, 1): Class 'AgoraTextureViewFactory' is not abstract and does not implement abstract base class member public abstract fun create(p0: Context?, p1: Int, p2: Any?): PlatformView defined in io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformViewFactory
e: /Users/doabletech/Development/Tools/flutter_sdk/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/agora_rtc_engine-5.1.0/android/src/main/kotlin/io/agora/agora_rtc_engine/AgoraTextureViewFactory.kt: (17, 3): 'create' overrides nothing

FAILURE: Build completed with 3 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':agora_rtc_engine:compileProfileKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
   > Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
see full [stacktrace][3] here (character limit)


==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':agora_rtc_engine:compileDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
   > Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
see full [stacktrace][3] here (character limit)


==============================================================================

3: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':agora_rtc_engine:compileReleaseKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
   > Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
see full [stacktrace][3] here (character limit)


BUILD FAILED in 4s
49 actionable tasks: 49 executed
```

Comment: if there is any other info need please let me know

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to build release version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68594930/unable-to-build-release-version)

Answer (score -1):

i found the issue, it's because i was using flutter dev channel,
if you have the same issue, make sure you are using the latest flutter stable version, to do this:

- run `flutter channel stable`

make sure your `pubspec.yaml` file has changed the flutter version to the stable version,

- run `flutter clean`
- run `flutter run`

you may get an error from `flutter lint` package, i solved this issue by removing it.

- source: [Github](https://github.com/AgoraIO/Agora-Flutter-SDK/issues/623#issuecomment-1068868260)

**edit: there seems to be a problem with flutter 3.0.0 causing the same error with agora, downgrading flutter to 2.12.5 solved the problem for me.**

Comment: it's not working for me

Comment: @AbirAhsan read the edit please.

Comment: I am using stable channel. 2.12.5 isn't available there. Which channel are you using ?

Comment: @AbirAhsan first i downgraded to 2.10.5 version, but it gave error because of null-safety, changing it to 2.12.5 solved it for me.
You can find the list of versions here:
https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/sdk/releases?tab=windows